# mysql empty rows

Tags: mysql

I have created a simple MYSQL database to store user information (id, FirstName, LastName)
and filled it with 3 names:

```
id | FirstName | LastName
1  | Sam       | Heyman
2  | Ben       | Eliott
3  | Al        | Readman
```

When I try and display the contents of the database in a table on my page, I get the correct number of rows but the cells are void.

```
User id | First Name | Last Name
        |            |
        |            |
        |            |
```

If I do

```
var_dump($rows)
```

I get the following:

```
array(6) { [0]=> string(1) "1" ["id"]=> string(1) "1" [1]=> string(3) "Sam" ["FirstName"]=> string(3) "Sam" [2]=> string(6) "Heyman" ["LastName"]=> string(6) "Heyman" }

array(6) { [0]=> string(1) "2" ["id"]=> string(1) "2" [1]=> string(3) "Ben" ["FirstName"]=> string(3) "Ben" [2]=> string(6) "Eliott" ["LastName"]=> string(6) "Eliott" }

array(6) { [0]=> string(1) "3" ["id"]=> string(1) "3" [1]=> string(8) "Alastair" ["FirstName"]=> string(8) "Alastair" [2]=> string(7) "Readman" ["LastName"]=> string(7) "Readman" }
```

So why are my cells empty? I have done many databases before and have never had this problem before. Having spent 3 hrs looking on google, I've given up.

This is the code:

```
<?php 
// Connect to server and select database.
$dbcnx = @mysql_connect('server','user','pw');
mysql_query('SET NAMES utf8;');
mysql_select_db('db', $dbcnx);
// Fetch all the users from the database
$users = @mysql_query('SELECT * FROM registered_users');
?>

<table width="400" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3" style="color:red;">
<tr>
<th>User ID</th>
<th>First name</th>
<th>Last name</th>
</tr>   

<?php
// Start looping through the rows in mysql database.
while($rows=mysql_fetch_array($users)){
var_dump($rows);
echo"<br />";
?>

<tr>
<td><? echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $rows['FirstName']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $rows['LastName']; ?></td>
</tr>

<?php
// close while loop
}
?>

</table>

<?php
// close MySQL connection
mysql_close();
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
<td><? echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $rows['FirstName']; ?></td>
<td><? echo $rows['LastName']; ?></td>
```

to either

```
<td><?php echo $rows['id']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['FirstName']; ?></td>
<td><?php echo $rows['LastName']; ?></td>
```

or

```
<td><?= $rows['id']; ?></td>
<td><?= $rows['FirstName']; ?></td>
<td><?= $rows['LastName']; ?></td>
```